# Door seal rubber - how to bring it back to shape?

Tags: doors, sealing

Wondering if anyone has got any ideas that doesn't involve taking the whole frame/door apart for the following issue...

There's a set of 4 bifold garden doors, and when installing a clip on blind the black rubber seal in one of the corners (top left) has gone a fair bit "in" rather than just "sitting" on the glass, and upon inspection I can see that along the beginning of the top part of the door there's a slight sag on the same rubber. My guess is that it lost some of the shape by going inwards.

I've tried to pull it back but to no avail, I can't quite get enough grip on it! There seems to be no leak caused by this, or any condensation forming, so it's mostly an aesthetic problem as far as I can tell but would still be nice to get it fixed since it's a brand new house!

Edit: Added a couple of pictures - one of the top rubber out of shape, and also one of the side so you can see what I mean by going "inwards" compared to the rest of the edge of the frame.

[image: "sagging" rubber]
[image: side, going "inward"]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include pictures of what you're talking about (clear focused pics, an overall so we can get our bearings, then a detailed shot or two). That will make it _much_ easier for people to help you.

Comment: Apologies for the delay on this - hope it's visible what I mean now?